# Disable security on elastic and kibana

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, kibana

Hello i'am new with elastic search.

I followed this documentation in order to enable security, i set a password with only number and that is the main problem.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/security-minimal-setup.html

I found the problem when I wanted to login in kibana .(the image bellow).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd0Gt.png)

Now i want to disable the security so i can work normally, or if there is some method which allow me change the password.

Comment: did you get a chance to look into my answer?

Comment: thank you for your help, yes i set xpack.security.enabled:false in elasticsearch.yml but the problem still persit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well I disabled xpack.security but the problem persist, so I go to the list of the settings in the keystore and then I removed elastic.password , so it's not required to login.

Answer (score 5):

I think you enabled the basic security using below config in your `elasticsearch.yml`

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

If you don't want that, you can simply disable it by changing it to `false` and restart your Elasticsearch nodes.

Comment: yes i set the xpack on false but always the same problem, i forget to mention that i create a user kibana_system ,and then i create a keystore ,and then i added the kibana password to the keystore

Comment: I am referring to the `elasticsearch.yml` in `D:\elasticsearch-8.4.3\config` path. But I dont find `xpack.security.enabled.`. Even the folder search doesn't help. could you please help me with the path of `elasticsearch.yml` ?